# how can i change listing order of my ul li list for each page load using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

hi i am using prevnext jquery slider . Now on each page load the sliding starting from the first list. Is there any way to list items in random order

Answer (score 0):

If I were to do this I'd probably use a query string idea i.e. http://www.mysite.com/index.html?1 , so I'd do:

```
var windowLocation = window.location.split("?");
if(windowLocation[1] === 1){
//show 1 slide
}else if(windowLocation[1] === 2){
//show another slide first
}
```

And so on...

Comment: Andrew Doves, Thanks for your reply. I corrected that problem by changing the value of 'w'. In previousnext.js there is a declaration var w =0; this variable references the position at which sliding starts. i changed that to var w= Math.ceil(Math.random()*4); where  4 is the total number of lists in my ul li list